# spring boot mondogb persist 3rd party classes

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB in my spring boot based application. I persist a set of entities which look like this:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String email;
}
```

It has some required annotations in order to be persisted by spring data.
Now I want to extract all entity classes from my maven module and include them in a new api-module which we'll be shared among other different modules in my project.

I don't want to include mondodb-related annotations into this module, I want it to be simple java classes like this.

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String email;
}
```

So when I will use it in my module (with mondogdb) I will have to add the appropriate annotations:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserEntity extends User {
}
```

So the only one way I can see is to extend POJO and enhance it with mongo annotations.

The question is are there any better ways how this can be implemented. Couldn't find any solutions yet.